# Embedded tomcat java application is running, but server cannot be reached

Tags: java, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-8

I am trying to set up a basic embedded Tomcat server and am unable to get the Tomcat server to run.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {

        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8888);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

Running this java app in Eclipse provides the output:

> June 19, 2019 12:00:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>
> INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]

And then waits until I hit stop, as expected, but when I run `curl localhost:8888` in the terminal, i get *curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8888; Connection refused*.

I've followed [this](http://zetcode.com/web/embeddedtomcat/) tutorial exactly, but I cannot seem to get the *server* to actually run. Also, `netstat -nlt` does not show the port `8888` being open.

My `build.gradle` has a single dependency:

```
implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.21'
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Have the same issue, followed the same article also

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just found solution
I use tomcat 9, and it looks like we need to call method `getConnector()` on `tomcat` object.

```
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(8080);
    tomcat.getConnector();
```

Answer (score 12):

Tomcat 9 no longer adds a Connector by default like previous versions.  You can do the following to add one:

```
final Connector connector = new Connector();
connector.setPort(port);
tomcat.getService().addConnector(connector);
```

As mentioned in another answer, you can also call `tomcat.getConnector();` which is a side-affecting getter.

Comment: For background/reference, this change was introduced in Tomcat 9.0.0 Milestone 14: [Stop creating a default connector on start in embedded mode](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60368). When you use [`new Connector()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html#%3Cinit%3E()), you get a `HTTP/1.1 NIO` connector by default.