# Simple Embedded Tomcat 10 Example

Tags: java, tomcat, embedded-tomcat, embedded-tomcat-10

I'm trying to get a simple embedded tomcat `10.1.0-M11` example working but I keep getting `localhost refused to connect` when I go to `http://localhost:8080/aa`.

Here is my code:

```
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setBaseDir("temp");
        tomcat.setPort(8080);

        String contextPath = "";
        String docBase = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();

        Context context = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, docBase);

        class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

            @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

                writer.println("<html><title>Welcome</title><body>");
                writer.println("<h1>Have a Great Day!</h1>");
                writer.println("</body></html>");
            }
        }

        String servletName = "SampleServlet";
        String urlPattern = "/aa";

        tomcat.addServlet(contextPath, servletName, new SampleServlet());
        context.addServletMappingDecoded(urlPattern, servletName);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

*Dependencies*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0-M11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0-M11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0-M11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0-M11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0-M11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**UPDATE**

I have gone through every single version I found that this bug was introduced in version `9.0.0.M4` and never resolved since then. Any newer version renders [this example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat) useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56668892/embedded-tomcat-java-application-is-running-but-server-cannot-be-reached), you need to add a Connector, which can be done like this:

```
...
tomcat.setPort(8080);
tomcat.getConnector();
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I have added 2-solutions and you can choose anyone so your final main function will be like the following:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setBaseDir("temp");
        // Solution 1
        //tomcat.setPort(8080);
        //tomcat.getConnector();

        // Solution 2, make server listen on 2 ports
        Connector connector1 = tomcat.getConnector();
        connector1.setPort(8080);
        Connector connector2 = new Connector();
        connector2.setPort(8090);
        String contextPath = "";
        String docBase = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();

        Context context = tomcat.addContext(contextPath, docBase);

        class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

            @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

                writer.println("<html><title>Welcome</title><body>");
                writer.println("<h1>Have a Great Day!</h1>");
                writer.println("</body></html>");
            }
        }

        String servletName = "SampleServlet";
        String urlPattern = "/aa";

        tomcat.addServlet(contextPath, servletName, new SampleServlet());
        context.addServletMappingDecoded(urlPattern, servletName);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getService().addConnector(connector1);
        tomcat.getService().addConnector(connector2);
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
```