# Embedded Tomcat starting but not listening

Tags: tomcat

I created a very simple Spring (no boot) app that I can package to a .war and deploy manually to Tomcat and it works correctly. Here is my project: https://github.com/gaetan-l/demo-spring-api

Now I would like to use an embedded Tomcat following [this github project](https://github.com/bobbrady/spring-rest-drill-bootless/blob/master/src/main/java/com/digibrady/interview/restdrill/config/AppMain.java), so I added to following class:

```
package gaetanl.demo.springapi;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class Application {
    public static final Optional<String> port = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("PORT"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String webappPath = "./build/libs";
        String warName = "demo-spring-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT";
        File war = new File(webappPath + "/" + warName + ".war");
        if (!war.exists()) {
            System.out.println("The .war has not been created yet (or is in another folder than ./build/libs)");
            System.out.println("Try running the gradle task \"assemble\"");
            return;
        }

        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(port.orElse("8080") ));

        // Tomcat base directory
        tomcat.setBaseDir("./tomcat.8080");

        // Application root for this Host, can be an absolute pathname, a
        // relative pathname, or a URL.
        tomcat.getHost().setAppBase("./work/Tomcat/localhost");

        // Adding a web application to a host's appBase (usually Tomcat's
        // webapps directory).
        tomcat.addWebapp("/" + warName, war.getCanonicalPath());

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

The .war is unpacked correctly in the embedded Tomcat's webapp folder, then the server seems to start correctly when I run the Application class, here is the console output:

```
16:09:07: Executing ':Application.main()'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :Application.main()
sept. 28, 2023 4:09:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
sept. 28, 2023 4:09:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.13]
sept. 28, 2023 4:09:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
sept. 28, 2023 4:09:11 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
sept. 28, 2023 4:09:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
sept. 28, 2023 4:09:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'
sept. 28, 2023 4:09:11 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher'
sept. 28, 2023 4:09:13 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 1553 ms
```

However I can't reach the server, when I try to do curl.exe -v http://localhost:8080/ I get the following answer:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
*   Trying [::1]:8080...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* connect to ::1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 2252 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
```

When I `try netstat -an | find "8080"` it doesn't find anything either. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: [Simple Embedded Tomcat 10 Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383171/simple-embedded-tomcat-10-example)

I needed to add `tomcat.getConnector();` right after `tomcat.setPort(...)`